# How does dimethyltryptamine cross the blood-brain barrier?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

Is there a specific chemical reaction that enables dimethyltryptamine to cross the capillary edothelial cells?

Answer (score 4):

Although serotonin and dimethyltryptamine (DMT) have similar chemical structures (see Jori's answer), serotonin is not transported across the blood brain barrier (BBB) ("[serotonin does not cross the blood–brain barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin)").  On the other hand, not only does DMT cross the BBB, it is one of the few compounds that is **actively transported** across the BBB.  While most compounds that cross the BBB do so by being lipid soluble (relatively small non-polar compounds) some molecules are assisted across the barrier through a variety of mechanisms.  Some of the known assistive paths include

- glucose carrier: transports glucose and several other sugars across the BBB
- phenylalanine carrier: transports a number of neutral amino acids across the BBB
- arginine carrier: transports several cationic amino acids across the BBB
- lactate carrier: transports several monocarboxylic acids across the BBB
- adenosine transporter: transports purine nucleosides as well as uridine
- organic cation transporter: transports a variety of cationic compounds, including monoamine neurotransmitters

There are more classes and sub-classes within each.  The following two references provide nice, readable overviews

1. [Small Molecular Drug Transfer across the Blood-Brain Barrier via Carrier-Mediated Transport Systems](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC539320/)
2. [Drug transport across the blood–brain barrier](http://www.nature.com/jcbfm/journal/v32/n11/full/jcbfm2012126a.html)

I don't know which of the above transporters is active in the case of DMT, but I strongly suspect it is the "organic cation transporter".  Here are some further references that relate specifically to DMT active transport across the BBB

- Takahashi T, Takahashi K, Ido T, Yanai K, Iwata R, Ishiwata K,
  Nozoe S (1985) 11C-labeling of indolealkylamine alkaloids and
  the comparative study of their tissue distributions. Int J Appl
  Radiat Isot 36:965–969
- Yanai K, Ido T, Ishiwata K, Hatazawa J, Takahashi T, Iwata R,
  Matsuzawa T (1986) In vivo kinetics and displacement study of
  a carbon-11-labeled hallucinogen, N, N-[11C]dimethyltryptamine.
  Eur J Nucl Med 12:141–146

They were found in this article, "[Bufotenine: Toward an Understanding
of Possible Psychoactive Mechanisms](http://bitnest.ca/external.php?id=%257DbxUgPZC%251A%2507%2503%257D%257B%257F%2503%2507IYQ%2502TWv%257Dd%2515Um%257DA)"

P.S.  We've all read fairy tales where kissing a frog turns the frog into a prince.  When the skin of the Bufo toad (Colorado river toad, sonoran desert toad and other members) is licked, a psychedelic experience results.  It is not illegal in the US to own the toad, although the Bufotenine is a controlled substance!  Anyhow, just wondering if this, or something similar, is what the fairy tales are based on.